# Runtime error in python code to reverse an array with user input

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm getting runtime error in this code to reverse an array with user input. How should I call the reverseList function to reverse the array. Is there a problem in indentation?

```
def reverseList(A, start, end):
        while start < end:
            A[start], A[end] = A[end], A[start]
            start += 1
            end -= 1
    
    t = int(input())
    for t in range(t):
        n=int(input())
        a = list(map(int, input().split()))
        A=""
        reverseList(A, 0, n)
        print(A)
```

Comment: "I'm getting runtime error" - what's the full error message?

Comment: @ForceBru
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ea526e0169edbcef90ebb11ae4dfebe1.py", line 13, in <module>
    reverseList(A, 0, n)
  File "/home/ea526e0169edbcef90ebb11ae4dfebe1.py", line 4, in reverseList
    A[start], A[end] = A[end], A[start]
IndexError: string index out of range